# Is it possible to use native C++ code to write a file on an iOS device

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, file-handling

I've C++ code which will generate an executable, to run some tests. The results of these tests will be dumped to a result file - results.log, in the current working directory of the executable.
This runs fine on Mac.

Can I use the same piece of code to be used on an iOS device? 
I've the results of my tests, in a vector in C++.
I heard that native C++ cannot write files on an iOS device. If so, what is the code I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you have the file extensions of *. m *. Rename mm where they the c + + code want to use.

this is a good guide for your question: http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects

Answer (score 0):

If your C++ code creates an *executable*, say a console program, then strictly, NO, since you need an iOS program to run on the device or simulator. However, it should be possible to incorporate the C++ sources into a regular iOS program, and possibly compiling as Objective-C++.